# PHP: MPDF export from multiple textares/textboxes

Tags: php, pdf, export, mpdf

So, I'm using MPDF to export data/content from one textarea. It works perfectly fine for one textarea, but what happens when I need to export multiple texboxes with a button click? Doing it this way (as shown below) it only exports the last textarea only. I need your help to figure this out how to export from multiple textareas. Thank you.

My form.
The textareas with its content is being echoed/displayed using a while loop as shown below.

```
<form method='post' action='thanks.php' enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <?php
  while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  ?>

  <textarea name="editor" id="editor">
  <?= $rows['Content']; ?>
  </textarea><br>

  <input type="submit" name="export" value="Export" id="export" class="btn third">

  <?php
  }
  ?>

</form>
```

Export coding.

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

if ((isset($_POST['editor'])) && (!empty($_POST['editor']))) {

    $pdfcontent = $_POST['editor'];

    $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
    
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($pdfcontent);

    // $mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
    // $mpdf->list_indent_first_level = 0;

    //output in browser
    $mpdf->Output('mypdf.pdf', 'D');

}

?>
```

Comment: Given the code you already wrote the question doesn't make much sense. Simply give the next textarea another name and concatenate its content to the `$pdfcontent` variable. That's far more basic than what you already have.

Comment: It is using a while loop to fetch the data from the database. So I cannot give the next textarea another name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give each textarea another name, so each one gets included when you submit the form. One way of doing this is to use a counter:

```
<form method='post' action='thanks.php' enctype="multipart/form-data">
<?php

$areaCount = 1;

while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    echo '<textarea name="editor_' . $areaCount . '" id="editor">'.
         $rows['Content'] . '</textarea><br>';

    $areaCount++;

}

?>

<input type="submit" name="export" value="Export" id="export" class="btn third">
</form>
```

Now when the form is submitted you have to find all the areas again:

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

if (isset($_POST['export'])) {

    $pdfcontent = '';
    $areaCount  = 1;

    while (isset($_POST['editor_' . $areaCount])) { 

        $pdfcontent .= $_POST['editor_' . $areaCount];
        $areaCount++;

    }

    $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
    
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($pdfcontent);

    // $mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
    // $mpdf->list_indent_first_level = 0;

    //output in browser
    $mpdf->Output('mypdf.pdf', 'D');

}

?>
```

Comment: There are errors in the code, for the while loop ..... while (isset($_POST[editor_' . $areaCount])) { .....  and the next one as well ......$pdfcontent .= $_POST[editor_' . $areaCount];.... So I changed it to ['editor_' . $areaCount].                                                                                             I tried it and it only exports the first textarea only.

Comment: @RohanChooramun Yes, sorry, missed two quotes there. There can be 2 reasons you only get the first textarea: 1. Only one got sent. 2. Only one got processed. To check the first use [the developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) to see what was sent. Can you report here what was sent? Remember, I cannot run this code.

Comment: I'm not really sure how and what to look for. Initially, I wanted a single button to export the textboxes. But your code will echo a button for each textbox, which I don't mind I can do it this way as well. When clicking on both buttons, they both export the first one only. Nevertheless, if this doesn't help find the link to my website below. (This is my free hosted personal university project). https://ebook-maker.000webhostapp.com/Ebook-Maker/user/inventory.php

Comment: Oh, yes, the submit button should be outside the loop. I'll change that. .... done. Does it work now?

Comment: Nop, both ways(submit button inside or outside the loop) only export the first textbox. You can check it in the link above.

Comment: @RohanChooramun I checked your link. The form is now working, both textareas are send to the PHP script, and both end up in the PDF. It seems to be working.

Comment: Ahh, it's now that I am realising that, I need them separate just as they are in their textareas. In this particular case I need to download two 2 pdfs. So depending on the amount of textarea, is it possible execute the mpdf export mulitple times?

Comment: @RohanChooramun Oh, I don't believe so. But never say never.... I advice you to ask a new question about this.

Comment: @RohanChooramun You probably need to do something with AJAX calls. I hope that's not too complicated?

Comment: Hello again. What if we use individual buttons for each textareas meaning the submit button is inside the loop like it was before you edited your code. Then just like the textarea we use name="export_' . $buttonCount . '" for the button. Is this possible?

Comment: @RohanChooramun Yes, that is possible, but each set of textarea and submit button then needs to be a separate form. This means the `<form> .... </form>` tag also needs to be inside the loop.

Comment: The code is working now. Not exactly how I initially wanted, which is using one button only but rather I'm using multiple buttons and forms. I'll be able to work with that. Thank you very much for your time.